# C++ Code::Blocks ios::in works, ios::out | ios::app not

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a very simple code written in C++ via Code::Blocks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string firstName, lastName;
int phoneNumber;

int main()
{
    fstream file;

    file.open("card.txt", ios::in);

    if (file.good())
    {
        cout << "File is good (read)" << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file (read)." << endl;
    }

    file.open("card.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

    if (file.good())
    {
        cout << "Enter your First Name: \n";
        cin >> firstName;
        cout << "Enter your Last Name: \n";
        cin >> lastName;
        cout << "Enter your Phone Number: \n";
        cin >> phoneNumber;

        file << firstName << endl;
        file << lastName << endl;
        file << phoneNumber << endl;

        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file (write)." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Card.txt file is located in the project main folder. From the first if value I get "File is good (read)". From the second one I get "Cannot open file (write)."

Really don't know why. Maybe Code::Blocks properties are set incorrect. For me they seem ok, they were not changed since installation.

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: Sure. Tried to run Code::Blocks in the administrator mode - same thing.

Comment: While checking `.good()` (e.g. `goodbit`) is okay, you probably want `if (file.is_open())`. The effect is the same, but using the `.is_open()` member function is generally the way it is done. Also consider using `std::string phoneNumber;` instead of `int`. Other wise, if the user enters any delimiter (e.g. `555-1212`) or any whitespace (e.g. `555 1212`) your read will only read `555`. If the user enters the formatted area code (e.g. `(512) 555-1212`, your read will fail entirely.

Comment: Nice advice, but that don't solve the problem. Data still cannot be written in the file.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. On Linux it compiles fine. Give me a minute to boot windows with Code::Blocks and I'll give it a go. What compiler are you using? MinGW or VS (`cl.exe`)?

Comment: It's MinGW. I'm using Win 11. Code is a simple example rewritten from the tutorial.

Comment: I fired up Win7 with Code::Blocks 17.12 and compiled your code with both MinGW and a very old VS (VS10 -- but I did have to change from `std::string` to `char[]` there). The `IOS::OUT | IOS::APP` is fine. That's just the old `"a"` (append) mode. It will create the file if it doesn't exits, but is happy to use an existing file as well. See: [std::basic_filebuf::open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

Comment: When you set up your project, were is your project located? Look in the menu at `Project -> Properties`, the project directory is on the first page. Make sure it isn't in `\Program Files\...`, etc.. That's the only other guess I have as to why opening for writing would fail. (not sure why admin mode wouldn't handle that though). Does Win11 have a Developer's Mode setting like Win10 does? That may be giving you problems (not sure why), but there is a ton of side-loading logic and code to prevent self-compiled `.exe`s (unsigned) from creating files on your system.